# How to map a function to a triple nested list and keep the triple nested list intact?

Tags: list, nested, python

I've have been building an analysis workflow for my PhD and have been using a triple nested list to represent my data structure because I want it to be able to expand to an arbitrary amount of data in its second and third levels. The first level is the whole dataset, the second level is each subject in the dataset and third level is a row for each measure that each subject.

```
[dataset]
      |
      [subject]
              |
              [measure1, measure2, measure3]
```

I am trying to map a function to each measure - for instance convert all the points into floats or replace anomalous values with None - and wish to return the whole dataset according to its nesting but my current code:

```
for subject in dataset:
    for measure in subject:
        map(float, measure)
```

...the result is correct and exactly what I want but the problem is that I can't think how to assign the result back to the dataset efficiently or without losing a level of the nest. Ideally, I would like it to change the measure **in place* but I can't think how to do it.

Could you suggest an efficient and pythonic way of doing that? Is a triple nested list a silly way to organize my data in the program?

Comment: Just for kicks, you can do it without list comprehensions or loops -- __don't do it this way__ -- `from itertools import repeat; dataset = map(map, repeat(map), map(repeat, repeat(float)), dataset)`

Comment: @agf, Great concept, although it's worth noting it only works in Python 3 or with the appropriate import.

Comment: @Mike You're right -- on Python 2 it's `from itertools import repeat, imap;
dataset = map(list, imap(imap, repeat(map), repeat(repeat(float)), dataset))`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than doing it in place, make a new list

```
 dataset = [[[float(value) for value in measure] 
                           for measure in subject] 
                           for subject in dataset]
```

Comment: +1 because the shape of the code reflects the shape of the resulting value.

Comment: Lovely stuff! That works a treat. I thought I had penned what you have described out in my program but got a Memory Leak error and concluded it was recursive. I'm pleased to say it isn't, many thanks Mike.

Answer (score 3):

`return [[map(float, measure) for measure in subject] for subject in dataset]`

You can return a list instead of altering it in place -- this is still remarkably efficient and preserves all the information you want. (aside: In fact, it's often faster than assigning to list indexes [citation needed], which is what others have suggested here!)

Comment: Why would you use `map` at the inner level instead of another list comprehension?

Comment: Less typing. I'm a sucker for less typing. I was going to add the list comprehension version after the fact, but Mike Graham had already posted that, and it would feel sort of like I was trying to absorb his answer, you know? They are equally valid. In fact one might argue that the list-comprehension-only version is more elegant, in that it uses fewer concepts as its building blocks. The difference is not really significant though, they're basically the same.

Comment: Agreed on all points. See my comment on the question for the least elegant way of all.

Comment: I will time it when I sit down tomorrow! Thanks for the answer Devin. I've ticked Mike's answer mainly, as TokenMacGuy says, it looks like the data structure its working on and thus is more readable and intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

A straight-forward way to do that in place would be:

```
for subject in dataset:
    for measure in subject:
        for i, elem in enumerate(measure):
            measure[i] = float(elem)
```

Alternatively, use the slice operator to upate the list in-place with the results of `map`

```
for subject in dataset:
    for measure in subject:
        measure[:] = map(float, measure)
```

Comment: +1 because I never think of reassigning using the full slice.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the job

```
for subject in dataset:
    for measure in subject:
        for i, m in enumerate(measure):
            measure[i] = float(m)
```