# Using functions on lists

Tags: python, list, function

I have a function that determines if the number is less than 0 or if there isn't a number at all

```
def numberfunction(s) :
    if s == "":
        return 0
    if s < 0 :
        return -1
    if s > 0:
        return s
```

i also have a list of lists

```
numbers = [[]]
```

now, lets say i filled the list of lists with numbers like:

```
[[1,2,3,4],[1,1,1,1],[2,2,2,2] ..etc ]
```

how would i go about calling up the function i had above into the numbers i have in the lists?

Would I require a loop where I use the function on every number of every list, or is it simpler than that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to map a function to a triple nested list and keep the triple nested list intact?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273164/how-to-map-a-function-to-a-triple-nested-list-and-keep-the-triple-nested-list-in)

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`map`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#map) and a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to apply your function to all of your elements. Please note that I have modified your example list to show all of the return cases.

```
def numberfunction(s) :
    if s == "":
        return 0
    if s < 0 :
        return -1
    if s > 0:
        return s

# Define some example input data.
a = [[1,2,3,""],[-1,1,-1,1],[0,-2,-2,2]]

# Apply your function to each element.
b = [map(numberfunction, i) for i in a]

print(b)
# [[1, 2, 3, 0], [-1, 1, -1, 1], [None, -1, -1, 2]]
```

Note that, with the way your `numberfunction` works at the moment, it will return `None` for an element equal to zero (thanks to @thefourtheye for pointing this out).

Comment: One minor thing, if `s` is `0`?

Comment: @thefourtheye I don't know :( the user does not define the case for `s==0` and so it will return `None`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also call nested `map()`:

```
>>> a = [[1,2,3,""],[-1,1,-1,1],[2,-2,-2,2]]
>>> map(lambda i: map(numberfunction, i), a)
[[1, 2, 3, 0], [-1, 1, -1, 1], [2, -1, -1, 2]]
>>>
```

I have Python < 3 in which map returns list.

Comment: @thefourtheye " partial application" ?

Comment: Yup, [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial)

Comment: @thefourtheye I tried but I could used partial()  :(

Comment: @thefourtheye I understood your code I will try partial with some more puzzles Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You could do it as:

```
result = [[numberfunction(item) for item in row] for row in numbers]
```

Comment: No love for list comprehensions I guess, +1 from me.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary, Haha... True. Thank you. I suppose `map` is more appealing. :P

Comment: @sshashank124 in Python <3 because in Python 3 you have to write `list(map(lambda i: list(map(numberfunction, i)), a))` that looks horrible :P